# Signalr Core WithAutomaticReconnect passing headers

Tags: c#, .net-core, signalr

I have gone through Signalr Core documenations and while I understand the feature

```
.WithAutomaticReconnect()
```

What I am curious is does it pass the headers still from the original request? Here my connect code which is working fine for most users, but it seems like I have some that on reconnect don't get added back into the pool. If someone can confirm the header info is passed that will save me some time from chasing this at least.

```
var hubAdjConnection1 = new HubConnectionBuilder()
                .WithUrl(url, options => {
                    options.Headers.Add("address", address);
                    options.Headers.Add("uName", uName);
                    options.Headers.Add("signature", signature);
                    options.Headers.Add("walver", Program.CLIVersion);
                })
                .WithAutomaticReconnect()
                .Build();
```

Again this code is working just fine I am just not sure the headers are passed  on the reconnect, but from I know the Automatic reconnect is suppose to return the same instance of the HubConnectionBuilder for chaining correct?

Or Do I need to somehow manually pass back the header information on a reconnect? I can't imagine that I do since there are no options to actually do that, at least that I am aware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those wondering I found a way to test this, though it was not easy to simulate a disconnect/reconnect all the time I did finally hit a reconnect instance and I did see that all the header information from the original HubConnectionBuilder() was passed along. Hope this saves someone some time as its not very clear in the MS documentation.